# Is pip already installed on python 3.6?

Tags: python, pip

This is a topic that I have not been able to find a straight answer for. Python's website (https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html) says that it is included from 3.4, but pip's website (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) says that is isn't included from python 3.4. Some youtube videos are telling me that it isn't already installed. Some questions on this page are telling me that it is. 
So, is it?

Comment: Depends on your Python distribution, I guess. On Debian, both ship separately.

Comment: On which OS? Anyway, I installed it on Windows and yes, unless you go and change the custom installation and exclude pip (uncheck it) by yourself, you will have pip installed when you install Python 3.6.

Comment: What part of the pip website makes you think it's not included with 3.4+?

Comment: It is on windows 10.

Comment: Your link to pip's website says "pip is already installed if you're using Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4 binaries downloaded from python.org".

Comment: pip is already installed if you're using Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4 binaries downloaded

Comment: Do you know what >= means?

Comment: @Someone the bottom line is, yes, it comes with your Python installation for your Windows OS.

Answer (score 1):

yes , python 3.6 already comes with pip .

You can check using `pip --version` in command prompt to check the version of pip installed .